# Locale changed programmatically, but app show in System default locale on Android 2.3.3

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator, android-fragments

My device system is in **English**.

In my **AndroidManifest.xml**, I defined my activity to check configuration changes:

```
<activity
   ...
   android:configChanges="locale" >
```

In my **Activity**, I add the function :

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {

      super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);



       Locale.setDefault(newConfig.locale);

       Log.v("*Locale is*", newConfig.locale.toString());

       getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(newConfig, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

}
```

In my **Activity** `onResume()`, I called the above function:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

     // I explicitely force my app to display in Finnish
     Configuration newConfig = new Configuration();
     newConfig.locale = new Locale("fi");
     onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

(My Activity hosts fragments, Each screen view is a Fragment.)

With above code, I suppose my app will show in Finnish when launched. It works fine on **Android 4.1.1**.

**But** when I run my app on **Android 2.3.3** device, the following thing happens:

**Scenario 1:** Launch the app from desktop ==> the app is showing in Finnish, **No problem**

**Scenario 2:** Login to my app, ==> then close the app ==> then, launch the app again from desktop ==> the app is showing **in English!! Why???**

(the log message  `Log.v("*Locale is*", newConfig.locale.toString());` shows me "**fi**" always!)

I verified that in Scenario 2, app **always show the system default Locale** when launch it again from desktop. Why?

I have no idea why in my Scenario 2, my app is showing in system locale English....any one could help?

Answer (score 2):

You can change the locale pragmatically like

```
public void setDefaultLocale(Context context, Locale locale) {
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        Configuration appConfig = new Configuration();
        appConfig.locale = locale;
        context.getResources().updateConfiguration(appConfig,
                context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        System.out.println("trad" + locale.getLanguage());
    }
```

and call this method like

```
setDefaultLocale(getBaseContext(), Locale.FRENCH);

setDefaultLocale(getBaseContext(), Locale.TRADITIONAL_CHINESE);

setDefaultLocale(getBaseContext(), Locale.ITALIAN);
```

Its your choice to which language you want to change and start your current Activity to reflect the changes.

Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);

Hi John, I tested from my side to overcome your Scenario-2
and after changing the locale pragmatically and go to home screen and again launch my application its is still to my changed language ie.e Italy.

I posted code in this [link](http://www.mediafire.com/?f0xr9fl833bbvhg/%22Code%22)

Please go through this and let me know it works for you.

Comment: Thanks, where should I call setDefaultLocale() & the startActivity(intent,2) then?

Comment: If you are giving option to select language by using spinner or AlertDialog with Single choice then on item select you can call setDefaultLocal() as well as startActivity(intent);

Comment: But, I have no problem on changing app language during selection. My problem is described in Scenario 2 of my post. That's when launch app and load locale from configuration, even I explicitly set Locale to finnish, the app starts with system default locale.

Comment: @John i edited and added a link at the below on my answer, from there you will get complete source code . For me your Scenario 2 is seems to be fixed and working fine.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like some bug in Android 2.x

Because if you change locale not in `onCreate()` but in `createMenu()` or inside some `spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener()` it will work.

It is workaround but try to call some event after start your app and change locale in it.